# UILabel on second View updates only once

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview, uilabel

I have a tableView, that upon clicking a cell, the tableView is resized and a second view slides into view. The second view contains more information about the selected record...

**NON-WORKING CODE**

```
if(frame.size.height > 600)
{

    CGRect detailFrame = StudyDetailView.view.frame;

    self.tableview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    detailFrame.origin.y = (frame.size.height-200);
    detailFrame.size.height = 200;
    [self.view addSubview:StudyDetailView.view];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.7];
        self.tableview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,frame.size.width,frame.size.height-200);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.2];   
        StudyDetailView.view.frame = detailFrame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

    StudyDetailView.ImageCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[StudyListData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] image_count]];
    [StudyDetailView.SeriesCount setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[StudyListData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] series_count]]];
    NSLog(@"This right after the view is set.. right?: %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[StudyListData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] series_count]]);

}
```

The ImageCount label (on the second view) only updates once, while the NSLog continues to show the correct values..

any suggestions?

**WORKING CODE**

```
CGRect frame = self.tableview.frame;
if(StudyDetailView == nil)
{
    StudyDetailView = [[StudyListDetailController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StudyListDetailController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:StudyDetailView.view];
}
if(frame.size.height > 600)
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 cell.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = YES;
```

try this see if it works. If not please give more details like the functions where you write the text in the UIlable

Comment: I was able to get it sorted. It turns out my code was creating the views one right over the other.. they are initially off screen so they didn't show up..

Answer (score 0):

You have created a custom class StudyDetailView Where you had added two labels and made their properties. I think there's something wrong in StudyDetailView class.
There's no problem in the above written code.

Can you post your code for figuring out the problem?

Comment: I just added it above..  The second view is initially created off screen. My code was creating a new view every time I clicked the cell, they just couldn't be seen off the screen... I added a check on the second view to ensure that there is only one..